# How to search for matches within lists all stored in one large list

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

The title for this one is hard. I have two main questions. First being, I want to set "self.Nnum" equal to "Selected_Nnum_and_Anum" within the "Page_Selector" function I created, so that I can continue to click through pages. Second, I need to create a search function that reads the "Namepages2" list in search of a match. The problem is that "Namepages2" is a list, filled with other lists (the number of lists within it can/will change). I am not sure how to find a match, I would like the function to output a value for "self.Nnum" as I type my desired item (from the original "Names" list) so I can display it in the "Page_Number" line edit.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QWidget

Names = ['Bob','Randy','Dakota','Steven','Clarke','Niomi','David','Nathan','James','Joe','Jacob','Jonah','Jerome','Jack','Jeremy','Jackson','Jamie']
Ages = ['51','32','22','19','40','27','19','45','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):                        # Window setup
    def __init__(self):                                       # Window setup
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()                      # Window setup
        centralWidget = QWidget()                             # Window setup
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)                  # Window setup
        self.setWindowTitle("ASSET")                          # Window setup
        self.OpenButton = QPushButton('Open',self)            # Creates the open button
        self.OpenButton.clicked.connect(self.Open)            # Links the open button to the "open" function
        self.SaveButton = QPushButton('Save',self)            # Creates the save button
        self.SearchBar = QLineEdit('Search',self)             # Creates the SearchBar LineEdit
        self.SearchBar.textChanged.connect(self.Search)
        self.PreviousButton = QPushButton('Previous',self)    # Creates the previous button
        self.PreviousButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.PreviousPage(self.MainFrame2.layout())) # Links the previous button to the "PreviousPage" function
        self.NextButton = QPushButton('Next',self)            # Creates the next button
        self.NextButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.NextPage(self.MainFrame2.layout()))         # Links the next button to the "NextPage" function
        self.Page_Number = QLineEdit('Page Number',self)      # Creates the Page_Number LineEdit
        self.Page_Number.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.Page_Selector(self.MainFrame2.layout()))
        self.MainFrame = QFrame(self)                         # Creates a frame
        self.MainFrame2 = QFrame(self)                        # Creates a frame
        self.MainFrame3 = QFrame(self)                        # Creates a frame
        self.MainHlayout = QHBoxLayout(self.MainFrame)        # Adds a Horizontal Layout
        self.MainHlayout2 = QHBoxLayout(self.MainFrame2)      # Adds a Horizontal Layout
        self.MainHlayout3 = QHBoxLayout(self.MainFrame3)      # Adds a Horizontal Layout

        self.Glayout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)             # Adds a grid layout to the main window
        self.Glayout.addWidget(self.MainFrame)                # Adds a frame to the main window's layout (it will be the top frame since it was added first)
        self.Glayout.addWidget(self.MainFrame2)               # Adds a frame to the main window's layout (this will be the middle frame)
        self.Glayout.addWidget(self.MainFrame3)               # Adds a frame to the main window's layout (this will be the bottom frame)
        self.MainHlayout.addWidget(self.OpenButton)           # Adds the open button to the top frame's layout
        self.MainHlayout.addWidget(self.SearchBar)            # Adds the search bar to the top frame's layout
        self.MainHlayout.addWidget(self.SaveButton)           # Adds the save button to the top frame's layout
        self.MainHlayout3.addWidget(self.PreviousButton)      # Adds the previous button to the bottom frame's layout
        self.MainHlayout3.addWidget(self.Page_Number)         # Adds the Page_Number LineEdit to the bottom frame's layout
        self.MainHlayout3.addWidget(self.NextButton)          # Adds the next button to the bottom frame's layout

        self.SubFrame = QFrame(self)                      # Creates a new frame
        self.SubVlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.SubFrame)      # Adds a vertical layout to the new frame
        self.MainHlayout2.addWidget(self.SubFrame)        # Adds the new frame to the middle frame
        self.Has_Been_Pressed = False                     # Sets the Has_Been_Pressed variable to False (will explain later)


    def Open(self):                                                     # This function is called when the open button is clicked
        self.Has_Been_Pressed = True                                    # This sets the Has_Been_Pressed variable to True
        self.Nnum = 0                                                   # Sets the Nnum variable to 0
        self.Namepages = []                                             # Creates an empty list
        BasicCounter1 = 0                                               # Sets the BasicCounter1 variable to 0
        BasicCounter2 = 1                                               # Sets the BasicCounter2 variable to 1
        while (8 * BasicCounter1) < len(Names):                         # Creates a while loop with the condition: while 8 * BasicCounter is less than the length of the list "Names"
            yN = Names[0 + (8 * BasicCounter1):8 * BasicCounter2]       # The new variable "yN" equals the list 'Names" from: 0 + 8*BasicCounter to 8*BasicCounter2
            self.Namepages.insert(0, yN)                                # Inserts "yN" to the blank list "NamePages"
            BasicCounter1 += 1                                          # Adds 1 to BasicCounter1
            BasicCounter2 += 1                                          # Adds 1 to BasicCounter2
        self.Namepages2 = list(reversed(self.Namepages))                # Reverses the list order of "NamePages"
        self.Namepage = self.Namepages2[self.Nnum]                      # Sets the specified numbered item (based on value of "Nnum") of list "NamePages" to "NamePage"

        self.Anum = 0                                                   # Exact Same as the last While Loop, but using a different list "Ages"
        self.Agepages = []
        BasicCounter3 = 0
        BasicCounter4 = 1
        while (8 * BasicCounter3) < len(Ages):
            yA = Ages[0 + (8 * BasicCounter3):8 * BasicCounter4]
            self.Agepages.insert(0, yA)
            BasicCounter3 += 1
            BasicCounter4 += 1
        self.Agepages2 = list(reversed(self.Agepages))
        self.Agepage = self.Agepages2[self.Anum]

        self.i = 0                                                                    # Sets the variable "i" to 0
        self.Widget_Counter = 0                                                       # Sets the variable "Widget_Counter" to 0
        while self.i < len(self.Namepage):                                            # Creates a while loop with the condition: while the variable "i" is less than the list "Namepage"
            if self.Widget_Counter <= 3:                                              # if statement that reads: if the variable "Widget_Counter" is less than or equal to 3
                    self.SubVlayout.addWidget(QLabel(self.Namepage[self.i], self))    # Adds a new label (that reads a specified item from "Namepage" depending on the value of "i") to the vertical layout in the subframe that was added to the middle frame
                    self.SubVlayout.addWidget(QLineEdit(self.Agepage[self.i], self))  # Does the same as above, but instead creates a LineEdit and fills it with a specified value from "Agepage"
                    self.i += 1                                                       # Adds 1 to "i"
                    self.Widget_Counter += 1                                          # Adds 1 to "Widget_Counter"
            elif self.Widget_Counter > 3:                                             # The other condition/path reads: if the variable "Widget_Counter" is greater than 3
                    self.SubFrame = QFrame(self)                                      # Creates a new frame. Since it shares the same name as the previous "SubFrame", the code will now refer to THIS one instead
                    self.SubVlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.SubFrame)                      # Adds a vertical layout to the new frame
                    self.MainHlayout2.addWidget(self.SubFrame)                        # Adds the new frame to the middle frame (which has a horizontal layout, therefore is to the right of the previous "SubFrame")
                    self.Widget_Counter = 0                                           # Sets "Widget_Counter" to 0

        # print(len(self.Namepages2))
        # print(self.Nnum)
        # print(self.Namepages2[1])

    def NextPage(self, layout):                                      # This function is called when the next button is clicked
        if self.Has_Been_Pressed:                                    # This if statement reads: if "Has_Been_Pressed" is True   (basically everything under the if statement will only run if the open button is pressed, bc that means "Has_Been_Pressed" = True)
            if self.Nnum < len(self.Namepages2) -1:                  # If statement that reads: If Nnum is less than the length of Namepages2 minus 1. This stops the loop from running when you reach the end of the list "Namepages"
                self.Nnum += 1                                       # Adds 1 to "Nnum"
                self.Anum += 1                                       # Adds 1 to "Anum"
                if layout is not None:                               # This if statement clears all widgets in the horizontal layout in "MainFrame2" (aka the middle frame)
                    while layout.count():
                        item = layout.takeAt(0)
                        widget = item.widget()
                        if widget is not None:
                            widget.deleteLater()
                        else:
                            self.clearLayout(item.layout())

                self.SubFrame = QFrame(self)                        # Creates another new frame called "SubFrame"
                self.SubVlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.SubFrame)        # Adds a vertical layout to the new frame
                self.MainHlayout2.addWidget(self.SubFrame)          # Adds the new frame into the recently cleared horizontal layout in "MainFrame2" (aka the middle frame)

                self.Namepage = self.Namepages2[self.Nnum]          # Changes Namepage to the next list in Namepages2 (this happens bc Nnum increases by one when the button is clicked)
                self.Agepage = self.Agepages2[self.Anum]            # Same idea
                self.i = 0                                          # sets "i" back to zero
                self.Widget_Counter = 0                             # sets 'Widget_Counter" back to zero
                while self.i < len(self.Namepage):                  # Same loop as before, but Namepage is different so it will display new data
                    if self.Widget_Counter <= 3:
                        self.SubVlayout.addWidget(QLabel(self.Namepage[self.i], self))
                        self.SubVlayout.addWidget(QLineEdit(self.Agepage[self.i], self))
                        self.i += 1
                        self.Widget_Counter += 1
                    elif self.Widget_Counter > 3:
                        self.SubFrame = QFrame(self)
                        self.SubVlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.SubFrame)
                        self.MainHlayout2.addWidget(self.SubFrame)
                        self.Widget_Counter = 0
                self.Page_Number.setText(str(self.Nnum + 1))
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

    def PreviousPage(self, layout):     # Same as "Next Button" but you're subtracting one from Nnum and Anum. The new Nnum limit is now zero.
        if self.Has_Been_Pressed:
            if self.Nnum >= 1:
                self.Nnum -= 1
                self.Anum -= 1
                if layout is not None:
                    while layout.count():
                        item = layout.takeAt(0)
                        widget = item.widget()
                        if widget is not None:
                            widget.deleteLater()
                        else:
                            self.clearLayout(item.layout())

                self.SubFrame = QFrame(self)
                self.SubVlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.SubFrame)
                self.MainHlayout2.addWidget(self.SubFrame)

                self.Namepage = self.Namepages2[self.Nnum]
                self.Agepage = self.Agepages2[self.Anum]
                self.i = 0
                self.Widget_Counter = 0
                while self.i < len(self.Namepage):
                    if self.Widget_Counter <= 3:
                        self.SubVlayout.addWidget(QLabel(self.Namepage[self.i], self))
                        self.SubVlayout.addWidget(QLineEdit(self.Agepage[self.i], self))
                        self.i += 1
                        self.Widget_Counter += 1
                    elif self.Widget_Counter > 3:
                        self.SubFrame = QFrame(self)
                        self.SubVlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.SubFrame)
                        self.MainHlayout2.addWidget(self.SubFrame)
                        self.Widget_Counter = 0
                self.Page_Number.setText(str(self.Nnum + 1))
            elif self.Nnum < 0:
                self.Nnum += 1
        else:
            pass


    def Page_Selector(self,layout):
        if self.Has_Been_Pressed:
                Inputted_Value = int(self.Page_Number.text())
                Selected_Nnum_and_Anum = Inputted_Value - 1
                if 0 <= Selected_Nnum_and_Anum < 3:
                    if layout is not None:
                        while layout.count():
                            item = layout.takeAt(0)
                            widget = item.widget()
                            if widget is not None:
                                widget.deleteLater()
                            else:
                                self.clearLayout(item.layout())
                    self.SubFrame = QFrame(self)
                    self.SubVlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.SubFrame)
                    self.MainHlayout2.addWidget(self.SubFrame)

                    Selected_Namepage = self.Namepages2[Selected_Nnum_and_Anum]
                    Selected_Agepage = self.Agepages2[Selected_Nnum_and_Anum]
                    self.i = 0
                    self.Widget_Counter = 0
                    while self.i < len(Selected_Namepage):
                        if self.Widget_Counter <= 3:
                            self.SubVlayout.addWidget(QLabel(Selected_Namepage[self.i], self))
                            self.SubVlayout.addWidget(QLineEdit(Selected_Agepage[self.i], self))
                            self.i += 1
                            self.Widget_Counter += 1
                        elif self.Widget_Counter > 3:
                            self.SubFrame = QFrame(self)
                            self.SubVlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.SubFrame)
                            self.MainHlayout2.addWidget(self.SubFrame)
                            self.Widget_Counter = 0

                    # self.Nnum = Selected_Nnum_and_Anum     # This will not work!
                else:
                    pass
        else:
            pass


    def Search(self, text):    # I have no idea where to start here!
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You could explain what your application does, besides I think it is too long I suspect that it can be implemented in a more elegant way, the confusion of the code prevents us from helping you.

Comment: The code, takes a list of names and ages and divides them into lists of 8. I use the lists to make pages you can click through with a next and previous button. The number of names and ages will change overtime, so I coded the application to accept any number of items in the two lists. I am dynamically creating frames, labels, and line edits to serve my purpose. I plan to be able to adjust the ages (since they're in line edits) and save them into new lists. But right now I just to create a search function that will find a name you type and tell you the page it is on.

Comment: The information you indicate in your comment is relevant so you must place it in your question. On the other hand, as your code suspects, it seems unnecessarily cumbersome and understandable code to your goal.

Comment: For my possible solution I will rewrite your logic for the reasons indicated in my previous comment, but from what I understand you only want to be shown the page number. With that page number are you going to do with the GUI? for example to establish that the current page is that page And if there are several coincidences that must happen?

Comment: I want the page number to appear in the "Page_Number" line edit. And if I want to go to said page number, I would click on the line edit, and press enter. I am having trouble setting the text in the "Page_Number" line edit to self.Nnum as well. I use self.Nnum to keep track of what page i'm on.

Comment: 1) And what happens if there are several matches in the search? 2) What is the match criterion? Should only match the first letters? Should it be differentiated between upper and lower case?

Comment: The search should provide the page number (aka self.Nnum) of the first match listed. The search does not have to differentiate between upper and lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP code is too long, messy and confusing to take as the basis of my solution so take the time to create my own implementation.

In this case I centralize the information in a model, associating the widgets via QDataWidgetMapper allowing the GUI and the model to share the same updated information. Another change was to use the appropriate widgets, for example if your data is numbers it is better to use a QSpinBox than a QLineEdit. Also if the number of items on a page is less than expected then the widgets are hidden.

Finally implement the search using the findItems() of the model.

All of the above is implemented in the following section:

```py
import math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class PageWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    openClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    saveClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, items_per_page=8, parent=None):
        super(PageWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.items_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2, self)

        self._current_page = -1

        self.open_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Open")
        self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Save")
        self.search_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Search")

        self.previous_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Previous")
        self.next_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Next")
        self.page_spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(maximum=0)

        self.open_button.clicked.connect(self.openClicked)
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.saveClicked)
        self.search_lineedit.textChanged.connect(self.search)
        self.page_spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.set_current_page)

        self.previous_button.clicked.connect(self.previous_page)
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next_page)

        completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(self)
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        completer.setCompletionMode(QtWidgets.QCompleter.InlineCompletion)
        completer.setModel(self.items_model)
        self.search_lineedit.setCompleter(completer)

        top_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        h_top_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(top_widget)
        h_top_lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        h_top_lay.addWidget(self.open_button)
        h_top_lay.addWidget(self.search_lineedit)
        h_top_lay.addWidget(self.save_button)

        bottom_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        h_bottom_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(bottom_widget)
        h_bottom_lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        h_bottom_lay.addWidget(self.previous_button)
        h_bottom_lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Page Number:"), 0)
        h_bottom_lay.addWidget(self.page_spinbox, 1)
        h_bottom_lay.addWidget(self.next_button)

        self._mapper_widgets = []
        items_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        items_grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(items_widget)
        items_grid_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        for i in range(8):
            name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            age_spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()

            widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
            lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            lay.addWidget(name_label)
            lay.addWidget(age_spinbox)

            items_grid_layout.addWidget(widget, i // 2, i % 2)
            mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
            mapper.setModel(self.items_model)

            mapper.addMapping(name_label, 0, b"text")
            mapper.addMapping(age_spinbox, 1, b"value")

            self._mapper_widgets.append((widget, mapper))

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(top_widget, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        lay.addWidget(items_widget, stretch=1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        lay.addWidget(bottom_widget, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)

        self._update_page(0)

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.items_model.clear()
        for values in data:
            items = []
            for value in values:
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                item.setData(value, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                items.append(item)
            self.items_model.appendRow(items)
        self.current_page = 0
        self.page_spinbox.setMaximum(max(0, self.number_of_pages - 1))

    @property
    def number_of_pages(self):
        return math.ceil(self.items_model.rowCount() / len(self._mapper_widgets))

    def is_page_valid(self, page):
        return 0 <= page < self.number_of_pages

    def get_current_page(self):
        return self._current_page

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def set_current_page(self, page):
        if self.is_page_valid(page):
            self._update_page(page)
            self._current_page = page
            self.page_spinbox.setValue(page)

    current_page = QtCore.pyqtProperty(
        int, fget=get_current_page, fset=set_current_page
    )

    def next_page(self):
        self.current_page += 1

    def previous_page(self):
        self.current_page -= 1

    def _update_page(self, page):
        items_per_page = len(self._mapper_widgets)
        start_index = page * items_per_page
        end_index = min((page + 1) * items_per_page, self.items_model.rowCount())
        indexes = list(range(start_index, end_index))
        for i, (widget, mapper) in enumerate(self._mapper_widgets):
            if i < len(indexes):
                widget.show()
                mapper.setCurrentIndex(indexes[i])
            else:
                widget.hide()

        self.previous_button.setEnabled(page > 0)
        self.next_button.setEnabled(page < (self.number_of_pages - 1))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def search(self, text):
        match_items = self.items_model.findItems(
            text, flags=QtCore.Qt.MatchStartsWith, column=0
        )
        if match_items:
            first_match_item, *_ = match_items

            name = first_match_item.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            print(name)

            row = first_match_item.row()
            page = row // len(self._mapper_widgets)
            self.current_page = page

    def to_list(self):
        data = []
        for i in range(self.items_model.rowCount()):
            name = self.items_model.item(i, 0).data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            age = self.items_model.item(i, 1).data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            data.append((name, age))
        return data


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.page_widget = PageWidget()
        self.page_widget.openClicked.connect(self.on_open_clicked)
        self.page_widget.saveClicked.connect(self.on_save_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.page_widget)

        self.resize(320, 360)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_open_clicked(self):
        items = [
            ("Bob", 51),
            ("Randy", 32),
            ("Dakota", 22),
            ("Steven", 19),
            ("Clarke", 40),
            ("Niomi", 27),
            ("David", 19),
            ("Nathan", 45),
            ("James", 1),
            ("Joe", 2),
            ("Jacob", 3),
            ("Jonah", 4),
            ("Jerome", 5),
            ("Jack", 6),
            ("Jamie", 7),
            ("Jackson", 8),
            ("Jamie", 9),
        ]
        self.page_widget.set_data(items)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_save_clicked(self):
        items = self.page_widget.to_list()
        print(items)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. I will eventually add many more items to the lists from txt files, and the save button will rewrite the text files with the updated info. This was exactly what I needed to move on to the final step of the application. Thanks again!!